# Inserting multiple JSON values from Postman to Postgres using Flask

Tags: python, flask, postman

I am trying to pass multiple JSON values from postman to PostgreSQL via Flask(Python). I can able to do it for single JSON data but not multiple values.

JSON Data:

```
{"users" : [{"username":"empty1","password":"6005"}, {"username":"empty2","password":"6006"}]}
```

Code:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from werkzeug.security import safe_str_cmp
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from model.user import UserModel
import ast
#from idna.core import unicode
#import argparse
user_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
user_parser.add_argument("username",required=True,location='json')
user_parser.add_argument("password",required=True,location='json')
class UserRegister(Resource):
    def post(self):
        args = user_parser.parse_args()
        args1 = ast.literal_eval(args.username)
        print(args1)
        list = []
        list.append(args1.copy())
        print(list[0])

        '''if UserModel.find_by_username(data['username']):
            return {"message": "A user with that username already exists"}, 400'''

        user = UserModel(**args)
        user.save_to_db()

        return {"message": "User created successfully."}, 201
```

Comment: Is there any error here you'd like to add?

Comment: No specific error but it returns a message whatever we put in the add_argument () without inserting second JSON data.

Comment: It's not really clear how `user_parser` is extracting more than one element from your list to insert into the database

Comment: When I execute the program, I am getting below result in postman
{
    "message": {
        "username": "Missing required parameter in the JSON body"
    }
}

Comment: Yes, because your parser is only seeing `{"users" : []}` as a top level object. Please show some effort into debugging this code. Your database method only expects individual json objects, or you must parse that new json object, and get the array and loop over it

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post but I faced the same issue and the below steps worked.
Once your Flask application is running -

1. Add your test in a collection in Postman and say `{{jsonBody}}` in the request body.
2. Set the below global variable in the Pre-request Script to "stringify" your JSON
   `pm.globals.set("jsonBody", JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.toObject()));`
3. Upload the JSON file when running the collection runner and "Save responses" to view logs.